# Is it possible to keep one published paper in two persons thesis?

Tags: thesis

Me and my colleague are working towards our PhD. We have worked on same problems (80%) over the past few years. We have published some papers based on the work we have done. We have decided to write thesis now. Is it possible to keep two or three chapters in both thesis identical (because we both did the same work). 
Thanks.

Comment: I am having hard time to understand the relation between the title and body of your question. Do you mean the shared chapters are kind of previously published papers and you both want to bring that publication in form of a chapter of your theses? Could you please [edit](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/42501/edit) your question and clarify?

Comment: If your university has rules about the minimum number of papers per PHD, usually they have to be unique per student. So, if the university requires 3 papers per PHD, you should have at least 6 joint papers.

Comment: Due to my work I have seen a fair share of PhD thesis in different fields. Occasionally you will come a cross identical chapters. I have not come a cross a thesis with more then one overlapping chapter. However this of course would not necessary mean this is impossible. But, every time there is an overlapping chapter it is already indicated on the published paper the first and second author should both be considered first author. 
Your SUPERVISOR should be able to answer your question, ask her/him